# UITextField Text-Emoji Automatic Replacement

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, emoji

So i'm working on a chatting app. I want user to be able to type in emojis directly from standard keyboard (not emoji keyboard).

ex. looking at any chatting app (mobile or PC/MAC) -> typing colon and bracket ex ":)" replaces it with an actual emoticon (smiley face -> unicode string). How is this implemented normally?

I guess I could create a dictionary with selected emojis I want to support

```
[
    (unicode: "\u{1F600}", matches: [":)", ":‑)", ":-]"],
    (unicode: "\u{1F603}", matches: [":D"]),
    (unicode: "\u{1F622}", matches: [":("])
]
```

then analyse input in shouldChangeCharactersIn - see if last 2-3-4 characters much some pre-defined text emojis - but this seems tedious and surely it's been done times and times before.. Are there any libraries that provide this mapping? All resources I see concern unicode values ..

Answer (score 1):

The tricky bit here will be working out when to check the users input and how much of it to check and then replace.  An iterative approach will work quite well.

If you want to cover all possible emojis you'll need to work with the unicode character sets.  However if you only want to replace a small subset the following works and is simple to implement.

To allow a quick check to be made if an edit to text has possibly added an emoji, create a character set of all possible emoji characters:

```
let emojiChars = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ":;-)(D"). //covers :) :-) ;) :( :-( :D etc
```

This enables a quick and relatively lightweight check to see whether the text could contain an emoji.  You need to check for all characters in the emojis in case, when working with the textfield delegate methods, the edit has added a character to existing text to create an emoji.  Check for any common characters between the text edited and the emoji character set.  eg.

```
If !emojis.intersection(CharacterSet(charactersIn: newText)).isEmpty {
  // do full search and replace
}
```

You could jump straight to a full search and replace but as that is relatively heavy work I'd pre-quality first.  Depending where you are doing this it may help to create the emojis characterSet as a static property so it is only generated once.

There are a number of ways to do the search and replace, but for a relatively small set of emojis I'd probably use a regex expression:

```
let emojiRegex = #"[:;]-?[)(D/]"#
```

and then use a dictionary to swap the emojis:

```
let emojis: [Substring: String] = [
   ":-D" : "",
   ":-)" : "",
   ";-)" : "",
   ":-(" : ""
]
```

Putting this all together creates an iterative method that will replace multiple emojis

```
func swapEmojis(in str: String) -> String {
   guard !emojisSet.intersection(CharacterSet(charactersIn: str)).isEmpty else {return str}
   guard let emojiRange = str.range(of: emojiRegex, options: .regularExpression), let emoji = emojis[str[emojiRange]] else {return str}
   return swapEmojis(in: str.replacingCharacters(in: emojiRange, with: emoji ))
}
```

You can use this in conjunction with the textfield's delegate methods or `textDidChange` notifications.

Comment: I like the optimisations. So well i guess building a custom map is required - I was mostly interested in whether there are some ready solutions for this part - i can't possibly cover all of it, not to mention 'standards' between chatting apps but i guess it's very 'flexible'...

Comment: Yes, if you want to do anythnig more than a small subset then this approach will probably  be labour intensive.  However it has got me thinking about how I'd do all emojis, and I;ll update it if I come up with a good anwser :-).  As emojis are all unicode values working across multiple apps/platforms apps shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can create an enum for the supported emojis. then, you can check whatever the user types in textfield's delegate. if it matches one of the emojis, you can replace the text and return that value.

Another solution could be applied if you want to use dictionary;

```
    var emojis: [String: String] = [
      ":)": "\u{1F600}",
      ":‑)": "\u{1F600}",
      ":-]": "\u{1F600}",
      ":-]": "\u{1F603}",
      ":(": "\u{1F622}"
   ]
```

then, in textField's delegate, you should check whether the text contains any of the keys or not. if it exist, replace the matched part with an emoji and return the value;

```
emojis.keys.forEach { (key) in
        if text.contains(key) {
            // replace the text with emoji and return the value
        }
    }
```